# Save script generated file in %Username%\Appdata.. in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have a Vbs that creates another Vbs in another location.

```
Option Explicit
dim fso,ofile
Const WR=2
set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")

set ofile= fso.opentextfile("C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Start-up\file.vbs",WR,true)

ofile.write "Dim objshell"
ofile.writeline "set objshell = wscript.createobject(""wscript.shell"")"
```

The code goes on but there is no problem with that other script. I'm wondering.. It says "C:\Users\Operator" but I want it to work for all computer. When I send it to a friend etc. Operator should be replaced with %USERNAME%. But I don't know how to do it in general and how to embed that in this code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Environment property of WshShell to determine what is AppData current location.

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim AppDataPath : AppDataPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("PROCESS")("APPDATA")
Dim Ofile : Set Ofile = fso.CreateTextFile(AppDataPath + "\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Start-up\file.vbs",True)
Ofile.writeline "Dim Objshell : Set Objshell = CreateObject(""wscript.shell"")"
Ofile.Close
```

Comment: That worked. THANK YOU SO MUCH. I tried to figure it out myself but I gave up after over an hour..

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `Operator` in the line:

```
set ofile= fso.opentextfile("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Start-up\file.vbs",WR,true)
```

Comment: I guess there has to be some other code at first to make that possible. Anyway I tried it and I says Line 6, Char 1, Error: Path not found Code: 800A004C Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

Comment: you have a problem with the quotes in the last line.

Comment: Also, try just writing `dir "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Start-up\" to check if the folder exists`